# Can a dragon PC be Resurrected?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, dragons

During this past week's session of D&D 3.5e one of our more experienced group members decided to push our ECL 5 limit and our temporary No Crazy rule (we are training a new player) and play a Freshly Hatched female White Dragon. (She calls my character "Mama" because I'm a Snow Elf and I wear a White Dragonhide Breastplate.)

A practical concern about a dragon PC occured to me: **Could she be resurrected if she died?**

If not I'd probably need to reincarnate her or something (I'm playing a Druid), but obviously Resurrection is preferable.

Comment: The group thought White Dragonhide made sense for camo in a snowy environment. so I was voted against and ultimately decided to humor them. now I have a Baby dragon who sits on my shoulder but is unhappy that I cannot talk to it.

Comment: Why doesn't it know Common? If it's got Int 12 or greater, it should, and any player who seriously sits down with a character that does not know Common is just causing problems... worst comes to worst, he should just burn the two skill points on Speak Language.

Comment: freshly hatched dragons dont know common. and my Druid doesnt know draconic. She is being taught by our ranger but it takes time according to my DM.

Comment: At present I know "Feed me Fish" and "Look out" and 2 or 3 other phrases. Im a slow learner. whereas In real life si mi bensvelk sva renthisjir mrith darastrixi.(Thats draconic wordz)

Comment: and so far we find it amusing and its a practical use of teaching another person a language they dont have.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[*Resurrection*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/resurrection.htm)

> This spell functions like *raise dead*
>
> [...]
>
> Constructs, elementals, outsiders, and undead creatures can’t be resurrected.

[*Raise Dead*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/raiseDead.htm)

> **Target:** Dead creature touched
>
> [...]
>
> Constructs, elementals, outsiders, and undead creatures can’t be resurrected.

Dragons aren’t listed, and so can be raised normally.

Comment: One.) I wasn't Sure and Two.) Since questions never get removed and instead are always here you never know when some new guy is gonna need to know this. although that is really just an unintended benefit. as Dr. House once said "Clarification, Its a beautiful thing.

Comment: @Novian When the rules are as clear as that, it's generally frowned on to ask a question "just to be sure." Question like that amount to "please read me the rule book" and aren't actually going to be helpful to anyone else. I mean, you're free to submit questions like that, but expect downvotes.

Comment: I guess im just having a Dumb Day feel free to take whatever administrative action is neccesary.